# Failed to execute script 'App-Name.py' due to unhandled exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller, executable

I made a python app using pygame and pygame-gui library. I've been getting this error when I try to run the python app that I've converted into an exe file. I used this command: `pyinstaller App-Name.py --hidden-import=data.jsonfile --onefile --noconsole` for creating the executable. And when I try to run it, it gives me this error:

Failed to execute script 'App-Name.py' due to unhandled exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI164642\data\jsonfile\theme-1.json'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "App-Name.py", line 508, in <module>
  File "App-Name.py", line 37, in __init__
  File "pygame_gui\ui_manager.py", line 68, in __init__
  File "pygame_gui\core\ui_appearance_theme.py", line 624, in load_theme
  File "importlib\resources.py", line 103, in read_text
  File "importlib\resources.py", line 82, in open_text
  File "importlib\resources.py", line 46, in open_binary
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 542, in open_resource
  File "pathlib.py", line 1117, in open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI164642\\data\\jsonfile\\theme-1.json'
```

I've tried looking for the answer anywhere but nothing works so far. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling pyinstaller or try other modules such as [cx_freeze](https://regilanj.wordpress.com/2017/06/07/py-to-exe-in-python-3-6-1/)